# Same number of outliers in LOF

Tags: scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, outliers, sklearn-pandas

I am running lof algorithm for around 100k 2d points. Each time, I run the lof algorithm with different n_neighbours parameter, I get the same number of points as outliers. It's always 10% of the points as outliers. Is this how this algorithm is supposed to work? Why does it occur this way?

Comment: Because the `'contamination'` param is 0.1 (10%) by default. Add the code for more explanation

Comment: Thanks, it's precisely this reason, I thought it figured out outlier number on its own